# Reading data from sql server and passing my password with special char in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to read a table from sql server using  PySpark and i am passing my password with special char and it's throwing an error  at my password

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
Spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("readdata").config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","/home/user/sqljdbc42.jar").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
jdbcDF = Spark.read.format("jdbc") \
 .option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://SVKSVP1234\SVLSQL908:1451\host;databaseName=NLX") \
    .option("dbtable", "customers") \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("user", "admin") \
    .option("password", "admin@123") \
    .load()
jdbcDF.show()
```

I am getting the error 
File "filesystem.py", line 8, in 
    .option("password", "admin@123")

I tried r"admin@123" and it didn't work for me
error i am getting
 File "filesystem.py", line 21, in 
    .option("password", "admin@123") \
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1007356/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1007356/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1007356/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1007356/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server_name = "<ServerName>"
database_name = "<DatabaseName>"
port = 1433
properties ={
    "user": "<user>",
    "password": "<password>"
}
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{}:{};database={}".format(server_name, port, database_name)

spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table="dbo.tablename", properties=properties)
```